# Star Wars Faction tags

Tags: discussion, tags

With the volume of Star Wars questions we have, would it be relevant to have tags that refer to major factions for questions that are not about a specific work or character but the group in general?

My suggestion would be for: `galactic-empire` and `rebel-alliance` to start. with maybe `first-order` and `the-resistance` with Episode VII out.

The only downside I see is that the wording may be too common and could cause confusion.

Comment: We do already have [tag:jedi] and [tag:sith] tags ...

Comment: "galactic-empire" is a problem because it's not restricted to Star Wars, but a tag for the Empire would be useful.

Comment: These tags seem largely worthless and prone to causing confusion. 'the-resistance' could apply to any one of a hundred [film and TV franchises](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LaResistance)

Comment: @Randal'Thor @Valorum, it may be of interest that there is now a `rebel-alliance` tag...

Answer (score 2):

My general thought is that any questions specifically about these groups will be easy to find with keyword searches, especially in combination with [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars).

Then we also need to think about how we'd use the proposed tags. Since they'd only be used on *Star Wars* questions, other tags would necessarily have to exist already (see above). But, then we'd have the tags being used wherever these factions are mentioned (because that's what happens with tags).

After that, we may look at what retagging would take. Due to the volume of *Star Wars* questions, retagging is likely not an option.

**So, overall, I'd vote no.** There are possibly other reasons to avoid them, such as the one @Richard pointed out in the comments.